# First Received Frame was not SETTINGS - Etcd Java

Tags: java, etcd

I am trying to run the jetcd client to access etcd running in a docker container on port 2379

I was using the docker image `elcolio/etcd:latest` and executed the following command to start the container:

```
docker run \
  -d \
  -p 2379:2379 \
  -p 2380:2380 \
  -p 4001:4001 \
  -p 7001:7001 \
  -v /data/backup/dir:/data \
  --name some-etcd \
  elcolio/etcd:latest \
  -name some-etcd \
  -discovery=https://discovery.etcd.io/blahblahblahblah \
  -advertise-client-urls http://10.x.x.x:4001 \
  -initial-advertise-peer-urls http://10.x.x.x:7001
```

and I am running only one instance. The container is started successfully and I was able to run the `etcdctl` on the container. But through Java, I am not able to run it.

Here is the code:

```
    import com.coreos.jetcd.Client;
import com.coreos.jetcd.KV;
import com.coreos.jetcd.data.ByteSequence;
import com.coreos.jetcd.kv.GetResponse;
import com.coreos.jetcd.data.ByteSequence;

import java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture;
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException;

public class Demo {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws ExecutionException, InterruptedException {

        Client client = Client.builder().endpoints("https://10.x.x.x:2379").build();
        KV kvClient = client.getKVClient();


        ByteSequence key = ByteSequence.fromString("/message");
        ByteSequence value = ByteSequence.fromString("test_value");

// put the key-value
//        kvClient.put(key,value).get();

// get the CompletableFuture
        CompletableFuture<GetResponse> getFuture = kvClient.get(key);

// get the value from CompletableFuture
        GetResponse response = getFuture.get();

        System.out.println(response);

// delete the key
        kvClient.delete(key).get();



    }
}
```

I am getting the following error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: io.grpc.StatusRuntimeException: INTERNAL: http2 exception
    at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.reportGet(CompletableFuture.java:357)
    at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.get(CompletableFuture.java:1895)
    at Demo.main(Demo.java:49)
Caused by: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: io.grpc.StatusRuntimeException: INTERNAL: http2 exception
    at com.google.common.util.concurrent.AbstractFuture.getDoneValue(AbstractFuture.java:531)
    at com.google.common.util.concurrent.AbstractFuture.get(AbstractFuture.java:512)
    at com.coreos.jetcd.internal.impl.Util.lambda$toCompletableFutureWithRetry$1(Util.java:125)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: io.grpc.StatusRuntimeException: INTERNAL: http2 exception
    at io.grpc.Status.asRuntimeException(Status.java:526)
    at io.grpc.stub.ClientCalls$UnaryStreamToFuture.onClose(ClientCalls.java:482)
    at io.grpc.PartialForwardingClientCallListener.onClose(PartialForwardingClientCallListener.java:39)
    at io.grpc.ForwardingClientCallListener.onClose(ForwardingClientCallListener.java:23)
    at io.grpc.ForwardingClientCallListener$SimpleForwardingClientCallListener.onClose(ForwardingClientCallListener.java:40)
    at com.coreos.jetcd.internal.impl.ClientConnectionManager$AuthTokenInterceptor$1$1.onClose(ClientConnectionManager.java:280)
    at io.grpc.PartialForwardingClientCallListener.onClose(PartialForwardingClientCallListener.java:39)
    at io.grpc.ForwardingClientCallListener.onClose(ForwardingClientCallListener.java:23)
    at io.grpc.ForwardingClientCallListener$SimpleForwardingClientCallListener.onClose(ForwardingClientCallListener.java:40)
    at io.grpc.internal.CensusStatsModule$StatsClientInterceptor$1$1.onClose(CensusStatsModule.java:678)
    at io.grpc.PartialForwardingClientCallListener.onClose(PartialForwardingClientCallListener.java:39)
    at io.grpc.ForwardingClientCallListener.onClose(ForwardingClientCallListener.java:23)
    at io.grpc.ForwardingClientCallListener$SimpleForwardingClientCallListener.onClose(ForwardingClientCallListener.java:40)
    at io.grpc.internal.CensusTracingModule$TracingClientInterceptor$1$1.onClose(CensusTracingModule.java:397)
    at io.grpc.internal.ClientCallImpl.closeObserver(ClientCallImpl.java:459)
    at io.grpc.internal.ClientCallImpl.access$300(ClientCallImpl.java:63)
    at io.grpc.internal.ClientCallImpl$ClientStreamListenerImpl.close(ClientCallImpl.java:546)
    at io.grpc.internal.ClientCallImpl$ClientStreamListenerImpl.access$600(ClientCallImpl.java:467)
    at io.grpc.internal.ClientCallImpl$ClientStreamListenerImpl$1StreamClosed.runInContext(ClientCallImpl.java:584)
    at io.grpc.internal.ContextRunnable.run(ContextRunnable.java:37)
    at io.grpc.internal.SerializingExecutor.run(SerializingExecutor.java:123)
    ... 3 more
Caused by: io.netty.handler.codec.http2.Http2Exception: First received frame was not SETTINGS. Hex dump for first 5 bytes: 485454502f
    at io.netty.handler.codec.http2.Http2Exception.connectionError(Http2Exception.java:85)
    at io.netty.handler.codec.http2.Http2ConnectionHandler$PrefaceDecoder.verifyFirstFrameIsSettings(Http2ConnectionHandler.java:350)
    at io.netty.handler.codec.http2.Http2ConnectionHandler$PrefaceDecoder.decode(Http2ConnectionHandler.java:251)
    at io.netty.handler.codec.http2.Http2ConnectionHandler.decode(Http2ConnectionHandler.java:450)
    at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.decodeRemovalReentryProtection(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:502)
    at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.callDecode(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:441)
    at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.channelRead(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:278)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:362)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:348)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:340)
    at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline$HeadContext.channelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:1434)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:362)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:348)
    at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.fireChannelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:965)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.AbstractNioByteChannel$NioByteUnsafe.read(AbstractNioByteChannel.java:163)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKey(NioEventLoop.java:644)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeysOptimized(NioEventLoop.java:579)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeys(NioEventLoop.java:496)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:458)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$5.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:897)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.FastThreadLocalRunnable.run(FastThreadLocalRunnable.java:30)
    ... 1 more
```

P.S: I tried to telnet on that port, and it worked fine. The curl also worked fine. There is no credentials I have put for the etcd.

Answer (score 4):

If you [convert](https://codebeautify.org/hex-string-converter) 485454502f to String, it shows: `HTTP/`

Seems like your program is trying to connect to a HTTP1 server, not HTTP2 (as stated on the trace).

> **[etcd3](https://hub.docker.com/r/xieyanze/etcd3) gRPC** *still holds a 2x message processing performance edge over
> etcd2.*
>
> ***gRPC
> uses HTTP2***

---

*Update it to, for example:*

**`docker pull xieyanze/etcd3:latest`**

Answer (score 0):

The problem highlighted by Asier is right. The workaround I got here is to download the etcd3 which supports http 2.0.
For this, I have downloaded the image:

https://hub.docker.com/r/xieyanze/etcd3

and then connected with it.

Answer (score 0):

When I use Java client 0.3.0 and my docker image is v2, I met the same question, so I update my image to v3 then solved the question.